# Retrieve Stations from Shoutcast.com

Tags: java, shoutcast

I am making a radio app in Java, and I want to get as many URLs as possible of streaming radio stations.

Is there a way to retrieve all that Shoutcast.com is offering? I found [this page here](http://wiki.shoutcast.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_Radio_Directory_API) but I can't configure what I am doing next. It requests a **Dev ID**. I am searching the forums... the night is [closer](http://www.shoutcast.com/partner_request_form) and [closer](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=322860)... I need some help.

**Also:**
Is there some way I can find ready lists online with available URLs of streaming stations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dev ID is almost certainly the Developer API Key that Shoutcast issues to authorized developers. It looks like you can request an API key [here](https://shoutcast.com/Developer).

And in terms of listing stations that are already playing, the page you linked contains a number of different ways to query that information directly through the API. That's probably the best official source of stations you're going to get. Of course, that means that you do need to acquire your API key first, but once you have that, it's all there in the wiki.

Comment: I am still unable to get the dev api key, filled up the form and even registered also, but still got no luck!!